# Oracle sqlplus - Error: not spooling currently

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, logfile, spool

Spool file is blank and getting error message "not spooling currently".
I am executing.

```
      sql>set feedback on
      sql>spool c:\test.log
      sql>@c:\testscript.sql
      sql>spool off
```

background: - I have created a job in job scheduler (windows) which writes the data into the txt files for oracle tables. I want to create a log file of execution.

Spool file should capture the command executed and if there is any error it should be written in the spool file.

Comment: The SQL\*Plus message "not spooling currently" implies that something in the script testscript.sql is already disabling spooling. Check that script to see if its SQL\*Plus commands are overriding the ones you set.

Comment: `not spooling currently` is not an error message.